# POST request working on localhost but not on azure

Tags: web-services, azure, asp.net-web-api, postmark

I am new to microsoft azure, but good with web api.

I have created web api services, and able to test it from postman tool when it is on localhost.
Now I have uploaded my services on azure and now I am not able to call it from postman tool.

```
Azure url: not working
http://******.azurewebsites.net/api/account/signIn
body
userName and password... both are string

localhost url: working
http://localhost:62676/api/account/signIn
body
userName and password... both are string
```

[image]

[image]

What do I need to change in services ? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to enable debugging mode for your web api service in Azure to see the detailed error message and stacktrace for troubleshooting.

Alternatively, you can also enable Remote Debugging for your web api and set the necessary breakpoint to debug through your web api in Azure.